# How to deal with a view with 14 buttons?

Tags: iphone

I have a view with 14 buttons, it looks quite ugly now. I use round rect button, and put the buttons 7 each side.

Maybe someone could recommend me some good custom button style?

here comes the screenshot.

I don't see any way to reduce number of buttons, so may be I can change the button style to make it look better, any recommend button style?

[image]

Comment: It depends. What do the buttons do? To clarify do they all "show a view" or can they be grouped to different types of behavior? This kind of info can help a designer with layout options.

Comment: Screenshot would be excellent.

Comment: When you've got that much clutter, changing how the buttons look probably wont help you. Have you considered removing some? Merging features together?

Comment: I can't tell what the app will do since I have signed a security contract, but you can imagine what it looks like. This app is used to record a kind of real-time activity so it requires as little as view layers as possible, that's why I'm putting 14 buttons on the top view so that uses can access functions more quickly.

Comment: Have you looked into a UITableView? that can be good for that type of situation..

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III thank you for alerting me, I didn't know that I must accept an answer before.

Comment: Maybe you'll get more help here (http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Perhaps a dropdown list?

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III also would you please tell me how to accept an answer that is in comment?

Comment: @Mauvis Ledford I don't think an extra operation to user is a good idea.

Comment: @user465191 you cannot, you can only ask the user to add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following approach ... In cases like this I use Custom buttons which are something as in image [image]

Now there are two appraoches to access individual button First being taking individual IBoutlets and connect each of the button one by one
    IBOutlet UIButton *_eventButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *_programButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *_sponsorsButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *_speakersButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *_mapsButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *_socialButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *_aboutButton;

and second being creating an IBOutletCollection and connect all these button to a single outlet
    //Alternative Approach

```
IBOutletCollection (UIButton*) NSArray*     mainButtonPanelArray;
```

Accordingly There can be either 8 different Methods

or a Single Method to access all the Button's Event

-(IBAction*)mainPanelButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    UIButton* btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSinteger buttonTag = btn.tag;

```
switch(buttonTag){
    case 111 :
        break;
    //and so on…            
    default:
        break;          
}
```

}

While The better User Interface would come with using custom Buttons with Images along.

Hope it helps

Comment: pretty good demonstration, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create the image you want, use it as the background for a Custom button.  The button can be a diamond, a circle, a picture of a cat -- whatever image you choose.